# Unit test ng-grid with Qunit

Tags: angularjs, qunit

I'm writing unit test for ng-grid by using Qunit frameword. Here is my implementation:

```
    module("Test grid angular", {
      setup: function(){
     injectorGrid = angular.injector(["ng", "ngGrid"]);
     $scope = injectorGrid.get('$rootScope').$new();
     $scope.currentPortfolioList = [
     { 
           'symbol': 'bbb',
       'available': 100,
       'mortage' : 0
     },
     {
       'symbol': 'AAA',
       'available': 0,
       'mortage' : 1000
     }];
       $scope.gridTest = { 
         data: 'currentPortfolioList',
         enableCellSelection: false,
         enableCellEditOnFocus: true,
         multiSelect: false,
         columnDefs: [
          {field: 'symbol', displayName: 'Ma'},
          {field: 'available', displayName: 'KL GD'},
          {field: 'mortage', displayName: 'KL CC'}
        ]
      };
    },
    teardown: function(){
      $("#gridview").html("");
    } 
  });

  test('hide column', function(){
    $scope.gridTest.columnDefs[0].visible = false;
    var el = '<div ng-grid="gridTest"></div>';
    var $compile = injectorGrid.get('$compile');
    var element = $compile(el)($scope);
    $("#gridview").html(element);
    $scope.$digest();
    var col0 = element.find(".col0");   
    ok(col0.length == 0);
  });
```

Although my test case is passed, I see an error message on console log of the Firefox browser as follow:

[$compile:ctreq] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.16/$compile/ctreq?p0=ngInclude&p1=ngInclude

\<\div class="ngHeaderScroller" ng-style="headerScrollerStyle()" ng-include="gridId' 'headerRowTemplate.html'"

I found that this error happens when calling: $compile(el)($scope);

Can you help me resole this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Use [Batarang](https://www.ng-book.com/p/Debugging-AngularJS/#angular-batarang) to look at the `nginclude` directive in question:

`gridId' 'headerRowTemplate.html'`

is not a valid reference.

> This error occurs when HTML compiler tries to process a directive that specifies the require option in a directive definition, but the required directive controller is not present on the current DOM element (or its ancestor element, if ^ was specified).
>
> To resolve this error ensure that there is no typo in the required controller name and that the required directive controller is present on the current element.

**References**

- [Error: $compile:ctreq
  Missing Required Controller](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$compile/ctreq)